# Define vector space on sphere!

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

Is it possible to define a vector space on sphere? If i have a space like $X$ homeomorphic to some topological space which is a vector space can i pull back the operation and make $X$ a vector space?

Comment: Well, the set-theoretic construction works in general. However, topological vector spaces are not compact, so they cannot be homeomorphic to a sphere.

Comment: Well, a sphere minus a point (as a set) can be endowed with a continuous sum and product by scalar.

Comment: What's the problem with this? Foe every a belong to plane a+infi= infi&a.infi=infi

Comment: Vector spaces do not contain a point which can be called "$\infty$" (inserting it would make most of the algebraic properties fail, and substantially change the theory), so I don't really understand your point.

Comment: Plane has one point less than sphere ,call that point infi for example

Comment: Ok, but that is not a vector-space structure. Vector spaces do not have an absorbing element.

Comment: Oh! Why?!i'm sorry but can u explain more please?

Comment: Let $z\in V$ such that for all $x\in V$ it holds $x+z=z$. Then, $0=z+(-z)=z$. But $0$ does not satisfy $0+x=0$ for all $x$ (unless $\dim V=0$)

Comment: In any vector space, if $v+w = v +u$, then $w = u$.  So if $a+ \infty = 0 + \infty$, then $\infty = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, with a topology on $V$, such that the operations of addition and scalar multiplication are continuous with respect to this topology, then I don't think there are any nice topologies which will do what you want.

As a set, any vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ looks like a subset of a product $$\prod\limits_i \mathbb{R}$$ of copies of the reals, consisting of entries which are zero at all but finitely many places.  The notation for such a subset is $\bigoplus\limits_i \mathbb{R}$.  I assume you want all the projection maps $\bigoplus\limits_i \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be continuous functions.  In other words, if $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$, and $v_0$ is one of the basis elements, then the function from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by $\sum\limits_i c_iv_i \mapsto c_i$ is continuous.

In this case, $V$ must contain the (subspace topology of) the product topology.  It follows that $V$ is not compact.  But the sphere *is* compact.  So putting a nice vector space structure on the sphere isn't possible.

Comment: What do you mean of nice structure?

Comment: Curve of sphere which in non zero doesn't matter?

Comment: Nice means addition and scalar multiplication are continuous, and the projection map onto any basis element is continuous.